# C strange bug... pulling my hair out

Tags: c

I had my code working earlier in the day on the unix machine, but when compiled under windows it gave me completely strange and incorrect output.

Since our code is going to be marked based on compilation on unix I thought hey that's good enough. But now I just finished refactoring my code (basically just adding comments, getting rid of variables which were never used in the program and getting rid of some functions which I wrote to test the program) and now suddenly my code seems to be giving me the proper output on windows and wrong output on unix.

Note that I have done nothing to modify the functionality of the code.

After spending so many hours working on this banging my head against Seg Fault errors through the week, this last minute bug is going to put it all to waste. What am I supposed to do when the bug is seemingly appearing at random?

Edit: The program is supposed to read a file similar to an html file and print out the tables. I'm loading the data of each individual cell onto a node in a Linked List and then printing out the info based on an algorithm. The output is working fine on windows now but not on unix. I don't even know what part of the code I need to look since I have no idea what's causing this.

Comment: You're giving way too little information for us to be of any help...

Comment: I'm not so sure you really stumbled on the legendary Heisenbug. Please provide more info. Code would be nice but compiler warnings and such could also help.

Comment: Maybe you could paste the problematic parts with some context... and btw, there is no such thing as random on a machine :P

Comment: "Note that I have done nothing to modify the functionality of the code" - I'm willing to bet you've done _exactly_ this :-)

Comment: Show us Code, or it didn't happen.

Comment: In its current form this is simply a rant.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the amount of information you supplied (next to none), the best guess is to look for uninitialized variables. That will produce different output on different platforms, and is a common beginner mistake in C.

Comment: I think Valgrind would be a good tool to run here, it will catch the uninitialized variables.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use **gdb** to debug your code and check where the segmentation fault is arising. That will give you a good hint of were to start looking, even though you don't remember to have done any modification.

There is plenty documentation on the web.
These are the basics:

> shell> **gdb** myprogram
>
> gdb> backtrace #lists the steps until the segmentation fault arises
>
> gdb> select 2 #You can select any step you want (e.g. 2)
>
> gdb> print number #print variables to hack around

There are a lot of features for gdb. I think this will give you a hint quickly.
Don't forget to use a version control system the next time. It's a safe and nice way of having your code organized and clean, and off course!, to avoid these terrible accidents.
(SVN or GIT are cool enough)

Answer (score 4):

## Step 1, make a copy of everything.

Copy the entire project somewhere.  Make a note of what state the project was in when you made that copy and the date:time.  DO NOT edit that copy.  You may even make the files unwritable if you want.  You need to be able to see what you have changed as well as go back to it.  Even though the program does not currently work on Unix, it does work under Windows, so you know that it does have some merit and is close to being useful to turn in.  When I get upset at a program I am writing or at the compiler for not understanding it (this happens a lot less now then it did 10 years ago) I tend to lose track of what all I am changing, so changing it back becomes difficult.  Using some type of version control (even just keeping extra copies around) will help you to keep track of what you have changes so when you make a mistake you can unmake that mistake pretty easily.  Differencing tools, like `diff` are very helpful when you know how to use them.  For right now you might want to try:

```
diff --minimal --side-by-side --ignore-all-space old_file.c new_file.c | less
```

Hopefully you are using a diff that supports those options because I think that they may be the most helpful for you in the short time that you have.  If you find that you need to fit more on the screen and your terminal window is large you can also add in the `--width=` command and give it a number of characters in a line on your terminal.

Anyway, make and keep lots of copies of your code until you know that you won't need them anymore (and maybe even then).

If you have graphical access see if `kdiff3` is available.  It may be easier for you to use quickly.  The 3 in its name refers to the ability to compare 3 versions of a file at one time (a common starting point and two edited versions of that file) and is useful, but you can learn about that later.  It is perfectly able to compare just two versions of a file and produce decent output.

## Step 2  Don't ignore warnings

I suggest that you compile it with the highest warning level possible with your compiler and *DO*  *NOT* ignore any warnings.  If you already have warnings without telling the compiler to issue more warnings then examine those first.  Warnings are there for a reason, and only occasionally should you ever encounter code the produces warnings that should just be ignored (and even then I usually add a comment about the expected type of warning and why it is not an error).  With `gcc` you can add the `-Wall` option to the compile command to issue all warnings.

```
gcc -Wall my_program.c -o my_program
```

Some may not make sense to you, but you can at least look at the code and see what might be unclear about it in the vicinity of the warning line.

## step 3 Use simple lines of code

Something that will make warnings easier to understand is using very simple to understand lines of code.  Trying to fit too much functionality into one line of code makes it so that any warning or error message about that line of code is much more difficult to understand.

## step 4 Use temporary variables

Temporary variables don't necessarily mean "my program uses more memory" but they do often mean the compiler gives more meaningful warnings because the data-types of variables in expressions are much clearer.

## step 5 Use functions

This is just a continuation of the philosophy from 3 and 4.  Functions make things easier to understand.  They also make it so that often when you find an error and fix it you don't have to worry about having copies of the erroneous code elsewhere in the program that also needs to be fixed (though you should still search for similar code just to be sure).

## step 6 assert

There is a macro (like a function, but not quite) called `assert` that lives in `#include <assert.h>` and can help you find all kinds of errors by making your program fail earlier than it otherwise would.  This sounds bad, but very often (especially with memory related problems like segmentation faults (SIGSEGV) ) programs are in a fatal state well before they die.  Using `assert` helps you to move their death to an earlier place so that you can see what their fatal mistake was, rather than just seeing the result of it.

`assert` takes as its parameter a boolean expression -- any comparison, integer, floating point number, or pointer will do.  Anything that you could use as a condition in an `if` or `while` will do.  If this expression is false (0 or NULL) then your program will die right there and on many systems it will give you a helpful error message about where the assertion that killed the program was located and maybe even what the assertion was.  There is another helpful thing that this causes which I'll talk about in a little bit, but for now, to use assert you just do:

```
  assert(x < y);
```

and if `x` is not less than `y` the program will abort (actually call the `abort` function).

This is helpful for things like:

```
 int clear_buffer(char * buffer, unsigned len)
 { /* len should be size_t but I don't want to explain that right now */
      assert(buffer);
      memset(buffer, 0, len);
 }
```

## Step 7, Use a debugger

If you have `gdb` on your Unix system then *GREAT*.  If not, you probably have some other debugger than you can learn how to use.  Many Unix C compilers take the `-g` option to mean "include debugging symbols", so add that to the other options you are passing to the compiler and recompile your program, and then do:

```
gdb ./myprogram
```

Which will print some stuff and then prompt you with:

```
(gdb)
```

Then you can set break points and all kinds of good stuff, but since you are in a hurry and getting crashes just do:

```
(gdb) r
```

Include any arguments after the r that you would be passing to your program when you normally ran it.  *gdb* will then run your program until something odd happens.  The something odd, in this case, should be a SIGSEGV (what UNIXes do to your program when it tries to access memory addresses that it shouldn't).  *gdb* will then prompt you with `(gdb)` again.  You can then do:

```
(gdb) bt
```

`bt` stands for back trace and *gdb* will print out the call stack, meaning all functions that were called to get to the current function.  You should see `main` near the bottom.  Look for the first function near the top that is a function you wrote.  This is where you need to start trying to find errors.  If the top function on the list is not one of yours then try issuing:

```
(gdb) up
```

Which will make it examine the previous function on the call stack.  Once in one of your functions say:

```
(gdb) list
```

And it will show you some code around the area where things are wrong.

To exit gdb you do:

```
(gdb) quit
```

And answer Y if it ask you if you really want to quit.

If you were to use `assert` and that killed your program then you would not end up with quite as much library stuff on top of the call stack to confuse you.

Sadly 3, 4, and 5 mess up the ability to get good info from diff so I suggest trying to limit your adding of this programming style into places where you are having errors or warnings already (at least for now).

I hope that this helps

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we will need your code to see what's going on. But if what you described is true then it is most likely that your code contains what's called undefined behavior. Undefined behavior can occur due to too many reasons, such as crossing array boundaries, incorrectly deleting pointers etc.etc. So, without code nothing can be said

Comment: @"nothing can be said", except what you just said which is very informative :)

Answer (score 1):

Run it through [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

I can guarantee you will find your error with valgrind.

If you've got access to a unix or linux machine, you should never release code that you haven't run through valgrind, even if the code works.

Answer (score 0):

With the data you've provided, here is my solution.

1. Take a break and zone out of the problem domain for a while.
2. Use a debugger, step through the program, identify where it is segfaulting.
3. Print data at the point of the segfault and validate it.

That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Compile your code with all warnings on.

Don't hide warnings with bogus casts, but take them seriously and resolve the real problems.

Use different compilers. On linux clang is a good alternative and gives way more indications than gcc.